# Div height taking up remaining view height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a (html) project and I need to have this situation:

I div that needs to be on the bottom of view area.  Then I need a div above that, that will fill the remaining view height.

```
<body style="overflow:hidden; width:100vw; height:100vh;">
    <div id="top" style="overflow-y:scroll;">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"><!--Needs to always be on the bottom of body-->
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</body>
```

The height of `#top` and `#bottom` cannot be percentages because the height of `#bottom` will vary due to changing content.

Comment: Did you mean, if you need some space to fill the view, it must be added to very first area?

Comment: yes, the top area needs to fill the available space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox` and set `overflow-y: scroll` for scroll area

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: lightgreen;
}
footer {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">Main<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque modi harum quidem impedit .</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```